# Canadian Citizen - Worked in USA - Now in Canada - Should I be filling a W9?

Tags: united-states, taxes, canada

I'm a canadian citizen.  I lived and worked in USA for 12-13 years under a VISA (Not a US citizen and not a permanent resident).  I've been back to Canada since 2011.  I do not own anything in USA.  Since in Canada I've been working for a Canadian Company.

When I opened my investment account (2011) they asked me if I had US issued social security number.  I said yes, so they asked me to fill in a [W9](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/fw9.pdf).  Was that the right thing to do?

Since I lived and worked legally in USA, I was issued a SSN and I still have the number.

---

As Heath pointed out bellow I should not have signed a W-9 From.  The canadian bank I use, had told me fill in the wrong form.  The people that work there do not know the difference between having a SSN and being a US person. After a month of going back and forth, today they told me that I had to fill in a W-8BEN which would apply from 2015 forward, for 2011-2014 they can't do anything...

Comment: 90% of the time if a government agency asks you to fill in a form its the choice between doing it and a visit from law enforcement. The other 10% is when you want something from them...

Comment: Do you actually have a US issued social security number?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, that was not the right thing to do.

A W-9 is the form used to certify that you are a U.S. citizen or resident alien for U.S. federal tax purposes. You want to fill out a W-8BEN, available on the [IRS website.](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/fw8ben.pdf) There is a spot on a W-8BEN for you to include your U.S. social security number. A Form W-8 is used to certify that you are NOT a U.S. resident for U.S. federal tax purposes.

Comment: Thanks @heath. That's what I believe as well. I'm not sure why the bank is insisting that I need to fill in a W9.  I'll try to follow up with the thread once I find out more.

Comment: Thanks - I would be curious to hear If the bank has a reason to do that or if they just don't know what they're doing. Good luck!

Comment: Most likely that specific person at the bank was just clueless. He remembered from his training "no ssn -> w8, yes ssn -> w9" and that's it